# Build a Pypet (Tatiana Tylosky) Double "For" Loop

Tags: python

I've just completed [Tatiana Tylosky's tutorial for Python](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/intro-to-python-tutorial/#Creating-Your-Pypet) and created my own Python pypet.

In her tutorial, she shows how to do a "for" loop consisting of:

```
cat = {
    'name': 'Fluffy',
    'hungry': True,
    'weight': 9.5,
    'age': 5,
    'photo': '(=^o.o^=)__',
}

mouse = {
    'name': 'Mouse',
    'age': 6,
    'weight': 1.5,
    'hungry': False,
    'photo': '<:3 )~~~~',
}

pets = [cat, mouse]    

def feed(pet):
    if pet['hungry'] == True:
        pet['hungry'] = False
        pet['weight'] = pet['weight'] + 1
    else:
        print 'The Pypet is not hungry!'

for pet in pets:
    feed(pet)
    print pet
```

**I'd like to know how to repeat this "for" loop so that I feed both the cat and the mouse three times.** Most of the Python guides I've read say that you have to do something like:

```
for i in range(0, 6):
```

In this case, however, the "for" loop uses the list "pets." So the above code can't be used? What should I do? I've tried some wacky-looking things like:

```
for pet in pets(1,4):
    feed(pet)
    print pet
```

Or:

```
for pet in range(1,4):
    feed(pet)
    print pet
```

Naturally it doesn't work. What should I do to get the "for" loop to repeat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would enclose your feed `for` loop in a `for` loop that iterates three times.  I would use something like:

```
for _ in range(3):
    for pet in pets:
        feed(pet)
        print pet
```

`for _ in range(3)` iterates three times.  Note that I used `_` because you are not using the iteration variable, see e.g. [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163/3001761)

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages let you embed one structure in another. Put your current loop under a for loop that runs three times, as @intboolstring's answer already showed. Here are two more things you should do now:

1. Don't compare against `True`. `if pet["Hungry"] == True:` is better written as

   ```
   if pet["Hungry"]:
       ...
   ```
2. Switch to Python 3. Why are you learning an outdated version of the language?

Comment: I've made that change, thanks. I'm actually using Python 3, but I just copied the code from the tutorial in order to make things simpler. My own code is a bit more complicated (perhaps too much so).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use nested for loops you could also extend the pet list temporarily like this:

```
for pet in pets * 3:
    feed(pet)
```

that works because `pet * 3` creates the following list: `[cat, mouse, cat, mouse, cat, mouse]`

If you need more control over the feeding order ( e.g. first feed all cats then all mice) the nested for loop approach might be better.